# What have astronauts used rolls of Kapton tape for?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, materials, astronaut-lifestyle, in-space-repairs

An image (also below) in an answer to the question "[How often is duct tape used during crewed space missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38824/26446)" shows a roll of the gray stuff next to a roll of Kapton tape, aboard the International Space Station.  **What do astronauts use Kapton tape for?**

We already have the question "[Why are crew EVA cuff checklists wrapped in Kapton tape?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21489/26446)" (with answer), so no need to repeat that.

Yes, Kapton is used extensively back on Earth in the design and manufacture of equipment, *but this question is not about that.*  It is about why the *astronauts in space* use it from a roll, either to make or repair something.

[image: gray and Kapton tape]

Comment: Just asked in the main meta: [Question "url" with quotes displays the actual question title during edit preview but not when edit is saved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363801/303080)

Comment: @uhoh: Thanks; that behavior seems new.  I just tried about a dozen ways to fix it.  What you see now seems to work, but isn't pretty.

Comment: Isn't it being used to stick something to the wall/divider/worksurface/etc in the background of that same picture?

Comment: I added the astronaut-lifestyles because they might use duct tape for fun and personal projects.

Comment: This questions has (one awesome but) far too few answers! I've encountered on this site numerous references to repaired satellites, including ISS.

Comment: "What have astronauts used rolls of Kapton tape for?" To obtain shorter pieces of Kapton tape.

Answer (score 8):

Kapton tape was used for various In-flight Maintenance (IFM) tasks on the shuttle.

> The Kapton tape was used to repair the standoff cross paint delamination of the Mir Docking Module Axial Target (DMAT) during STS-79 (STS-79 CHIT 015). However, it
> was officially added to the IFM tool locker for STS-86 and subs.

Source: Shuttle IFM tool catalog ( https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/shuttle_ifm_tool_catalog.pdf )

The Shuttle IFM Checklist has more examples of how it was used, but I have not found it online.

During the STS-120 EVA to repair a torn ISS solar array blanket, Kapton tape was used:

> Parts of the suit and the
> tools were taped with insulating
> Kapton orange tape. The tape would
> keep electric charge from conducting
> between the array and the tool.
>
> ...
>
> Parazynski was told not
> to touch the array with his gloved
> hand. Instead, he had with him a tool
> that had been built inside the ISS, a few months prior, to keep a swaying
> array from contacting a crew member
> during an EVA on an earlier mission.
> This tool, called the hockey stick,
> was made of nonconductive material
> wrapped in Kapton tape.

[image]

From [The International Space Station - Operating an Outpost in the New Frontier](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/iss-operating_an_outpost-tagged.pdf) page 320

Answer (score 3):

During STS-126 mission to the ISS, astronaut Don Pettit famously used a plastic sheet and Kapton tape to create an open container "Zero-G" cup for drinking beverages like coffee and tea in microgravity. Teardrop-shaped cup exploited fluid's surface tension to hold the fluid and its taped edge acted as a wick to direct fluid to the sipping point. One minute into the following video he describes how he crafted it.

https://www.space.com/6154-astronaut-invents-coffee-cup.html

On ISS, Expedition 66 cosmonauts Anton Shkaplerov and Pyotr Dubrov prepared a [Herring Under A Fur Coat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dressed_herring) using a mould made out of a plastic sheet and Kapton tape.

News article: https://ria.ru/20211230/seledka-1766132679.html

[image][image]
[image][image]